# Error when getCollection Product

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I get this error in browser  `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48 bytes) in D:\xampp5\htdocs\m2\final\vendor\magento\module-eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity.php on line 216`

Basiclly from block i **getCollection** like this

```
protected function getProductCollection()
{
    $limit = $this->getProductLimit();

    // @var Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
    $collection = $this->productCollection->create()
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured', 1)
        ->setPageSize($this->getCollectionSize())
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

Entire code here [github](https://github.com/mrtuvn/m2ce.dev/blob/mrtu_lappy/app/code/Tuna/FeaturedPro/Block/Home/FeatureList.php)

This extension only show featured products

What happens with my code? how to fix it

Iam using magento 2 stable version

Comment: increment the memoery zie and time in php.ini and restart

Comment: i already set it to 768M

Answer (score 0):

This this way in your phtml file

```
<?php $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection()?>
<?php print_r($productCollection->getData();
//OR
if($productCollection->getsize()) {
    foreach($productCollection as $product) {
        echo $product->getId(); 
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice in Magento2 is to use repository to get data. You can get a filtered list of products using the method 'getList'. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Api/ProductRepositoryInterface.php#L74

With your approach try to increase php memory limit to 2G.